# Modifying docker image to work with gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab pages site that is built inside a docker container. I found a base image that contains 95% of what I want. With my old ci, I was installing extra packages before the build step. I want to create a new image with these packages installed, and use that image. I was able to build and run this image, but it no longer runs in gitlab actions. I'm not sure why.

- Git repo: https://gitlab.com/hybras/hybras.gitlab.io
- CI Config:

```yaml
image: klakegg/hugo:asciidoctor-ci # old
image: registry.gitlab.com/hybras/hybras.gitlab.io # new

variables:
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
  SSHPASS: $SSHPASS

pages:
  script:
  - gem install asciidoctor-html5s # remove these package installs in the new version
  - apk add openssh sshpass # remove these package installs in the new version
  - hugo
  - sshpass -p $SSHPASS scp -r public/* $HOST_AND_DIR
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

- Successful Job: Installs the packages, builds the site, scp's it to my mirror
- Dockerfile:

```
FROM klakegg/hugo:asciidoctor

RUN gem install asciidoctor-html5s --no-document \
    && apk --no-cache add openssh sshpass
CMD hugo
```

- Failed CI Run: `Error: unknown command "sh" for "hugo"`

Comment: When you can, place your code, errors, etc. in the post itself using the [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of uploading images or links to code/errors/etc. This helps make your question more readable, and prevents issues if the links ever change.

Answer (score 0):

As it can be seen in your pipeline, there is an error:

> Error: unknown command "sh" for "hugo"

It means that you haven't `hugo` installed on the image you've been using. In order to solve this problem, you can use the official docker image of [Hugo](https://hub.docker.com/r/klakegg/hugo/). For this purpose, you have to use its image or install hugo on the image you are using.

#### 1. Using Hugo image:

Add the following lines to the stage you want to use hugo:

```
<pipeline_name>:
    image: klakegg/hugo
```

#### 2. Install Hugo on existing image

Check out [this page](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/installing/) to find out how to install the Hugo on different distribution of your base image.

For example you can install Hugo on ubuntu using the following command:

```
<pipeline_name>:
    before_scripts:
        - sudo apt-get install hugo
```

#### 3. Install Hugo in your Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add hugo  # Or something like this!
```

Comment: My image is based off of the hugo image. Doesn't that mean it comes with hugo?

Comment: @Hybras What do you mean by "based off of"?

Comment: Using `FROM` means my image contains everything in the image after `FROM` right?

Comment: @Hybras yeah!  That’s the base image.

Comment: I already used the image u linked as the base. The base image has hugo